# Get list of email addresses from ADGroup

Tags: c#, active-directory

If I have the name of an Active Directory group, how can I get a list of the members or their email addresses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    string groupName = "somegroup";
    string domainName = "somedomain";

    using(PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
    {
        using(GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, groupName))
        {
            var sams = from x in grp.GetMembers(true) select new {x.SamAccountName, };
            var users = from sam in sams.Distinct()
                let usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, sam.SamAccountName)
                select new { usr.SamAccountName, usr.DisplayName, usr.EmailAddress};
            //do something with users...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great! I can get the user info but I don't see the email address for each user. How can I get each member's email address?

Comment: There you go. There are various ways to cycle through the data of course. The important thing is that you can get the UserPrincipal by the SamAccountName. The UserPrincipal has the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

in this url are a good and complete articule about AD with C# http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#42, user are stored as DiretoryEntry review the property Properties
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.properties(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: For .NET 3.5 and newer, you should start looking into using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` which has a much nicer, much easier to use interface (`PrincipalContext` and `UserPrincipal`) that's much more productive to use. `DirectoryEntry` is very low-level and notoriously hard to use ....